# Qt6.2 and Multimedia Module

Tags: c++, qt, multimedia, qt6

As Qt6.2 released, it seems that the multimedia module will come back and today i download qt6.2 but "qt += multimedia" still doesn't work.
How can i use the multimedia module or have an alternative to play a sound effect in c++?

p.s. i'm using qt6.1 before.

Comment: There is still no release for Qt 6.2, could you explain where you installed that module from. See https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_6.2_Release

Comment: Qt 6.1 was released on May 6 so I do not think there is a release soon, according to the calendar the 6.2 release is expected for September

Comment: i just install it with qt maintenance tool and its name is qt6.2

Comment: It is probably an alpha version that has not been completed. My recommendation is that you wait for an official release.

Comment: if it hasn't been released, how can i play a sound effect with qt6.1 in c++?

Comment: Well, you can't, use another library that does it or wait for Qt 6.2. Note: We are not interested here if you have a homework. If you want to use QtMultimedia then use Qt5, no need for Qt6

Comment: You should switch to Qt5 for this likely 5.15.2 if that is available on your platform.

Comment: thx and i've already made it using qt5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as I know, QMultimedia and QMultimediaWidgets are not present in the Qt 6.1 release. If you look att the following list, there are all the removed modules. (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew60.html#removed-modules-in-qt-6-0)

Also, if you look at the Qt 6.2 available modules, they don't appear neither: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtmodules.html

Qt claims that those modules may be included in a future release (i hope this happens), but for the moment you'll need to stick with Qt5.

(Sorry for my english)

## EDIT:

Starting from Qt6.2, the QMultimedia module is available again (but QMultimediaWidgets still not present)